# data structure for side scrolling game

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I was just wondering what the best data structure would be to use to represent data objects in a side scrolling game, basically the stuff the user can't see isn't on the stage so I would generally create a custom class to define its properties (x,y,weight,type, derp, etc) and then push that into an array and as the user moves forward I project the info from the array while checking if their x position is appropriate.

The problem that can occur is that the user can move left and right so whats the best way to keep track of the indexes?

Thanks

Comment: No need to keep track of the indexes. Just keep track of where the player is and only bother with indexes in range of the players location.

Comment: but that will take O(n) every time I move, its too computationally draining

Comment: If your objects' coordinates are changing, you'll have to iterate over them anyway. Unless your objects are fixed, you'll have to check everything on every frame.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you have long level with lot of objects and you don't want to check linearly all of them to see what should be on screen. You need to split your data into chunks and make a list of those chunks. It reminds me of [Quadtrees](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadtree), if your shooter is linear, your tree becomes 1D and it's simpler to implement.

Structures you might use:

**Node** - contains range (xmin, xmax) and list of children Nodes or Leaves. All Nodes are plugged into hierarchical structure, where root one is the whole game world/level, root children are regions, then subregions and so on. Number of levels in the tree depends on how large number of objects is.

**Leaf** - has range too, contains data objects corresponding to this region.

When you have built this tree, locate object from given range should take O(log N) time.

**EDIT:** I'll try to illustrate it to make more clear.

If your level is 1D, you don't need full quadtree, only linear tree:

```
                  root node, xmin = 0, xmax = 1000
                   contains list of regions:
                  /   |   \
                 /    |    \
    region 1,         |     \
xmin = 0, xmax = 300  |      \
                      |       \
                region 2,      \
              xmin = 301,       \
              xmax = 650         region 3, xmin = 651, xmax = 1000
                                  |                   |
                   Leaf, xmin = 652, xmax = 850       |
                   list of objects                 Leaf, xmin = 851, xmax = 1000
                   in that range                   list of objects

public class GameObject
{
    public var x:Number;
    //other stuff
}

public class Node {
    public var xmin, xmax:Number;
    public var children:Vector.<Node>;

    public function writeObject(object:GameObject):void
    {
        for each (var node:Node in children)
        {
            //find node with corresponding range
            if (node.xmin > object.x && node.xmax <= object.x)
            {
                node.writeObject(object);
                return;
            }
        }
        throw new Error("Children not found!");
    }

    public function findObjects(xmin:Number, xmax:Number):Vector.<GameObject>
    {
        //there comes the tricky part
        //1. build list of leaves in that range
        //2. filter first and last leaf (they may be only partially in the range)
        //3. copy objects from leaves between first and last as is
        //4. return list of objects
    }
}

public class Leaf extends Node {
    private var objects:Vector.<GameObject>;

    public function writeObject(object:GameObject):void
    {
        objects.push(object);
    }
}
```

First you need to create nodes connected in the tree, choosing regions quantity depending on your level. Then you write your objects into structure and think hard how to get them later :)

Comment: how does the tree become 1D, are you saying that create a tree for every node that is interested? So we have our main quadtree but each node in the quad tree is a tree itself?

Comment: Forget about quadtrees, it's simple plain tree, I must remember that in the first place...

Answer (score 0):

When you say "project info from the array", what do you mean? Do you want to display that information to the player or do you just want it available for use? If you just want it available:

If you had to keep track of the indexes of the array, you might be able to do some element match - oterate through your array to find the first element that is shown onscreen, and then add the number of objects onscreen to that number to find the last element. This would require keeping track of displayed elements, however, perhaps via a boolean inside your custom class.

Upon reflection, though, do you really need to keep track of the indices? If the player can move backwards or forwards, and there can be a variable number of objects onscreen, it may be better to iterate over the entire array on every frame and check for valid x/y values; if x/y are within stage bounds, display the object. Using this method, you could easily have element [2] and element [89] displayed onscreen, even if the values in-between were gone. (For instance, if those scroll offscreen, but element [2] has followed the player character thus remaining onscreen.) This way, you avoid having to worry about array keys and the left/right movement. Basically...

```
//psuedocode.
for each in Array {
   if {x/y aren't valid) don't display;
   else display;
}
```

Using a Vector to hold your objects will make this even faster if all of your objects are of one type (or inherit from one type).

I hope that made sense and I hope I understood your question, but it's really late and I'm really tired, so I'm sorry if it didn't. Let me know.